# Views node Theming

Tags: views, theming

I'm working on a site in Drupal 6, and I've created a page view as I wanted, and it displays in a table.

Unfortunately, the theme that I'm using has a sidebar Region which doesn't collapse even when it has no block in it. Due to this, I would like to take away the sidebar as I would like the table that renders my views to stretch across the content area.

Even though I've copied the theming information, I'm kind of confused of how to create a template to show the view in the page without the sidebar region.

Someone help.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick css trick that will hide the side bar in this page view :

1 Open firebug and inspect the body tag and find out the class with the name of your view ex :

In my case my view name is : page marque and I find in my body tag this :

```
<body class="not-front not-logged-in page-parmarque one-sidebar sidebar-left">
```

2 With firebug inspect the container of your sidebar id or class , suppose that your sidebar id = left-sidebar this piece of css code will resolve the problem :

```
.page-marque #left-sidebar{
    display:none;}
```

this will hide the sidebar only in your page view , replace .page-marque and #left-sidebar with your values

Or there is a solution with jQuery alternative for your case : 
add this code to a javascript file and add it to .info file and flush caches

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  if(window.location.pathname == "/property-listing"){
  jQuery("#content").css({"width":"auto"});
}
})
</script>
```

Comment: I've edited the answer and this javascript snippet will do the work for you